# Does C++11 force move unconditionally?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I compile the following code using command `g++ -std=c++11 t.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring> //memcpy()
class s
{
    char *p;
    size_t size;
public:
    s(){
        size=10;
        p=new char[size];
    }
    s(const s &other){
        size=other.size;
        p=new char[size];
        memcpy(p,other.p,other.size);
    }
    ~s(){ delete [] p; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<s> ss;
    ss.push_back(s());
}
```

This is `gdb` log:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at t.cpp:23
23          ss.push_back(s());
s::s (this=0x7fffffffe370) at t.cpp:9
9               size=10;
10              p=new char[size];
11          }
std::vector<s, std::allocator<s> >::push_back(s&&) (this=0x7fffffffe350, 
    __x=<unknown type in /tmp/a.out, CU 0x0, DIE 0x20d0>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:932
932       { emplace_back(std::move(__x)); }
std::move<s&> (__t=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:102
102     { return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&>(__t); }
std::vector<s, std::allocator<s> >::emplace_back<s>(s&&) (this=0x7fffffffe350)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/vector.tcc:94
94      if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
101       _M_emplace_back_aux(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
102       }
s::~s (this=0x7fffffffe370, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at t.cpp:17
17          ~s(){ delete [] p; }
std::vector<s, std::allocator<s> >::~vector (this=0x7fffffffe350, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:425
```

From the log, I am in the following impression:

1. GCC ignores copy constructor `s(const s &other)`.
2. GCC automatically creates a `move` constructor for `class s` and then `std::vector.push_back()` calls that `move` constructor.

   [This article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1916419) states

   Thus, if the definition of class C doesn't explicitly
   declare a move assignment operator, one will be implicitly
   declared as defaulted only if all of the following conditions
   are met:

   My question here is that `class s` apparently has a user-declared destructor `~s()`, meaning `class s` does not meet the forth condition and thus GCC should not enforce `move` on `std::vector.push_back()`. How does GCC behaves so?
3. Destructor `~s()` is called two times: first immediately after temporary `s()` has been passed as argument to `ss.push_back(s());` **and moved**, and second after the destructor of `std::vector<s>` is called.
4. Because this code does not meet [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), it is doomed to crash when the destructor of `std::vector<s>` is called. The content pointed to by `p` in object `s` is already deleted by the first `~s()`. Therefore, `std::vector<s>` destructor calling `~s()` must crash with error like `double free or corruption`.

However, much to my surprise, somehow this program runs and terminates normally.

**question 1**: Why the program does not crash? Am I simply lucky?

**question 2**: According to `gdb` log, does it mean that codes designed for prior C++11 meeting `rule of three` but not meeting [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), like this example, are very likely to crash when they are compiled to C++11 executables?

**EDIT**:

This question was raised due to my misinterpretation of `gdb` messages like these:

```
std::vector<s, std::allocator<s> >::push_back(s&&)
emplace_back(std::move(__x));
std::vector<s, std::allocator<s> >::emplace_back<s>(s&&)
```

which lead me to think that GCC creates a move constructor. I just did as many these experts told me to - setting a break point in `s(const s &other)`, and noticed that the program does stop there. This finding invalidates all my questions.

As every expert here suggested, the facts are:
 1. GCC does not create any move constructor.
 2. The existing copy constructor is called.

Thank you all for the big helps!

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the copy constructor. Does the program stop at that breakpoint?

Comment: This `push_back` internally calls a function named `std::move` in order to initialize the new element, but this initialization uses the copy constructor (because there's no move constructor and the copy constructor is the best match). No move constructor is generated or called.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just did. Yes, the program stops in the copy constructor.

Comment: @cpplearner You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmmm, check this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring> //memcpy()
#include <iostream>
class s
{
    char *p;
    size_t size;
public:
    s(){
        std::cout<<this<<"\tdefault constructor\n";
        size=10;
        p=new char[size];
    }
    s(const s &other){
        std::cout<<this<<"\tcopy constructor\n";
        size=other.size;
        p=new char[size];
        memcpy(p,other.p,other.size);
    }
    ~s(){ 
         std::cout<<this<<"\tdestructor\n";
         delete [] p; 
    }   
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<s> ss;
    ss.push_back(s());
}
```

For me, I am getting destructed 2 different object:
*0x7fffc879aa50 default constructor

0x1668c40   copy constructor

0x7fffc879aa50  destructor

0x1668c40   destructor*

> question 1: Why the program does not crash? Am I simply lucky?

There is no double free of coraption.

compiled with:
g++ -O3 --std=c++11 file2.cpp -o file2.out
G++ 4.7.3

Comment: Message `0x1668c40 copy constructor` successfully removes my concerns although I think the two `destructor` messages do not prove that the two contents pointed to by two `p` are different.

Answer (score 8):

> GCC ignores copy constructor s(const s &other).

It may well do that, as a copy-elision optimization.

> GCC automatically creates a move constructor for class s and then std::vector.push_back() calls that move constructor.

No. A move constructor is not generated.

> My question here is that class s apparently has a user-declared destructor ~s(), meaning class s does not meet the forth condition

Correct. The class also doesn't meet the first condition (user declared copy constructor).

> How does GCC behaves so?

GCC seems to behave as it should. There is no move construction or assignment involved.

> Destructor ~s() is called two times

In the gdb log that you show, I only see one instance of `s::~s` being called.

> question 1: Why the program does not crash? Am I simply lucky?

I would consider you unlucky. It seems that `push_back` didn't use the copy assignment operator, so the conditions for double free didn't occur.

> question 2: According to gdb log, does it mean that codes designed for prior C++11 meeting rule of three but not meeting rule of five, like this example...

This example doesn't meet the rule of three, so this appears not to be example of what you're asking for.

> are very likely to crash when they are compiled to C++11 executables?

No. As long as code follows the rule of three, it is safe to copy the objects. Following the rule of five is only necessary in order to make the object movable (to avoid copying).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed this example code does not meet `rule of three`. I omitted `copy assignment operator` to keep the code as short as possible for easy reading and hoped to have better chance of getting helps. Apparently I made it too short.

Answer (score 3):

If a copy constructor is explicitly declared (as in your case) no move constructor or assignment constructor are automatically generated by the compiler.

The copy constructor is the best candidate and is used to copy the temporary generated element (both default and copy constructor are invoked).

This also gives you [strong exception safety guarantee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety).